# Unable to Run Consul Localy

Tags: .net-core, service, microservices, consul, service-discovery

Getting the following error message when trying to start Consul Service.

[image]

Comment: How have you configured the service? Did you follow https://learn.hashicorp.com/consul/datacenter-deploy/windows? Are there any logs from Windows Event Viewer that you can share which would show why Consul is not starting?

Comment: Thanks @BlakeC. Its working after restart. Although I did restart but it was not working. 2nd time restart did the work. Thanks